# Using NoSuchElementException then looping is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to check if a webpage has a certain element with a try/catch function, and then, depending on the result go thru a loop. Not quite working for me. I get a time out exception on the imgsrc3 line. Probably something obvious but I'm just not getting it!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from splinter import Browser
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException   

# driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
browser = Browser('firefox')
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://superrare.com/clairesalvo")
time.sleep(5)


def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,35).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'profile__bio']")))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
while(True):
    imgsrc3 = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'profile__bio']")))
    for i in imgsrc3:
        bio = i.text    
else:
    bio = "none"
```

Comment: thx everybody who commented... still quite new to software dev... really helpful comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a function but not invoked it.

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,35).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    except TimeoutException:
        return False
    return True

if check_exists_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'profile__bio')]"):
    imgsrc3 = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'profile__bio')]")))
    for i in imgsrc3:
        bio = i.text    
else:
    bio = "none"
```

Comment: Thx again for that. Your suggestion works only for web pages where the field is present. I still get the timeout exception with pages where the class is not present. I also used the `//div[@class='profile__bio']` as the xpath filter as suggested below. Strangely it didn't work with my initial filter. No idea why. Also strangely, for pages where the class is not present the exception occurs on `try: WebDriverWait(driver,35).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))`

Comment: @RemiCastonguay thanks for the feedback. I see the issue. We should `except TimeoutException` since `WebDriverWait` throws `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thx @Max. Will try tonight!

Comment: Yup, @max daroshchanka, that did it! Thx so much for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `xpath` filter should be:

```
//div[@class='profile__bio']
```

Also, you don't seem to use the function `check_exists_by_xpath` that you decalared.

And your `while(True)` loop will never exit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in your code that I would like to point out:

## Not invoking your function

You are creating your function but you are never invoking it

## Identation problem

there is an identation problem, this line

```
while(True):
```

and all the code after it, is out of the check_exists_by_xpath function.

## Unused parameter

you are passing `xpath` parameter that you are not using anywhere in the function:

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
```

## Infinite loop

If you use `while(True):` you are creating an infinite loop that is never gonna stop unless you use a `break` inside it

```
while(True):
    imgsrc3 = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'profile__bio']")))
    for i in imgsrc3:
        bio = i.text
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).